# Dustjs OR helper

Tags: dust.js, dust-helpers, dustc

How to write below statement using dust helper?

```
{@eq key="device" value="windows || Linux"}
     Your system is Windows or Linux based.
{:else}
     Your system is MAC based.
{/eq}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@any` helper with the [Select Helper](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers/#select-helper) to achieve this:

```
{@select key=device}
  {@eq value="windows"/}
  {@eq value="Linux"/}
  {@any}Your system is Windows or Linux based.{/any}
  {@none}Your system is MAC based.{/none}
{/select}
```